# Could I install Caffe framework on my laptop?

Tags: caffe

My graphics card

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3410/3430] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30e9
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
        Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 7000 [size=256]
        Memory at 98400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Expansion ROM at 98420000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

So i do not have NVIDIA card,does this mean I can not install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. You can install it with `CPU_ONLY=ON` variable in cmake. Of course, **CUDA** will be unavailable for you, but you still can use **caffe** on CPU.

Moreover, you can try to checkout *opencl* caffe branch to utilize your AMD hardware (but I didn't try it yet).